# how to show error message which is passed by the server when using $asyncValidators

Tags: angularjs

```
<ng-form name="myForm">
                <div ng-show="myForm.text{{$index}}.$error.printValidator">
                you cannot print {{data}} !!
                </div>
                <div>
                <textarea name="text{{$index}}" placeholder="{{textSection.text}}" ng-model="getUserTextSction(textSection.textStyleID, area.userPageText).text" print-validator ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"> </textarea>
                </div>
</ng-form>
<a ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click='completeEditPage("/article/")'>
```

above is my html code and below is javascript code

```
            angular.module('editorApp')
            .directive('printValidator', function ($http, $q,baseService) {
            return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "ngModel",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var checkPrintable = function (modelValue, viewValue) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var value = modelValue || viewValue;

                var param = {};
                param.text = value;
                return $http.post(
                    '/api/edittexts/CheckPrintable/',
                   param, {
                       headers: {
                           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                       }
                   })
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.ngChar) {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('printValidator', false);                           
                        alert("you cannot print："+response.data.ngChar);
                        deferred.reject(response.data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('printValidator', true);
                        deferred.resolve;
                    }
                    return deferred.promise;
                });
            }
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.text = checkPrintable;
        }
    }
})
```

the code above worked well.when user typed unprintable characters it shows an error message...

Now I have two questions:
the first one is how can i show the unprintable characters which is passed from the server side (actually it is "response.data.ngChar") in the  tag at " {{data}}" ??
(it means ,how to get the deferred.reject's parameters in the html)

the second one is how can i disable the submit botton when there is unprintable characters errors?
I use "ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"" but it doesnot work.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are doing some very complicated stuff for a very easy job.

How i would set this up is something as the following:

```
<div ng-if="!data">Fetching data...</div>
<div ng-if="data && data.length > 0">Unprintable characters: {{data}}</div>

<a ng-disabled="data && data.length < 1" ng-click="completeEditPage("/article/")">
```

Your variable 'data' will be set when the data is retrieved asynchronously. When data is being retrieved, $scope.data will be undefined making your div 'fetching data...' visible

When your variable 'data' gets set by the asynchronous function. the fetching data... div will disappear and you can view another div based on the 'data' not being undefined.

Now the only thing you need to do is set $scope.data when your function finishes.

so... $scope.data = response.data;

(Hoping that your response.data is an array)